# VueJS SPA with cakePHP backend regularly gives timeout

Tags: php, vue.js, centos, axios, cakephp-3.0

I developed a single-page application in VueJS2, a POS system which is backed by a cakePHP backend.
The frontend does frequent api calls through AJAX to the PHP backend using the axios library. The axios library has a timeout set to 10000ms.

A limited number of hardware devices can use this application. Max number of devices that can login & use the application will be around 50-60.

The application runs smooth but the application returns periodic timeouts: a "Error: timeout of 10000ms exceeded". Even on the most basic functions.

F.e. each 30s an API call is triggered to check if the token that's used to login is still valid. If not, the user gets logged out. It's a very simple function that doesn't do much, I just need to do this request so I can check the request and log the user out if the token isn't valid anymore.
(This specific function quite often returns this timeout). Also there's no specific pattern. Some days it doesn't happen, some days quite often. It's not the only function that triggers a timeout. Some others do, but most of the time it's this one.

Rollbar error logging: [image]

```php
public function check()
{
 if (!$this->getRequest()->is('get')) {
   $this->_respondWithMethodNotAllowed();
   return;
 }

 exit('ok');
}
```

The application runs on a cloud VPS, high-end centOS (6.10) server containing 16GB of RAM and 8CPUs. The Apache is using MPM worker and has a Server Limit/Max Request Workers value of 512. Hardware doesn't seem the issue, I would guess?

Anybody got any suggestions I could look into?
I've been tweaking quite some server settings, but that didn't solve it so now I'm running out of options :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any firewall or any other rate-limiting mechanisms deployed ?

Comment: Not that I know of actually

Comment: Turn on error reporting in php and check if logging is enabled in CakePHP, analyze the apache logs.

Comment: If the problem is on the PHP side, check whether you have enabled [**metadata caching**](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.8.0/config/app.default.php#L275) (see also **https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/database-basics.html#metadata-caching**), and that the [**model cache**](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.8.0/config/app.default.php#L126) duration is long enough (it's [**shortened in debug mode**](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.8.0/config/bootstrap.php#L90-L95)).

Comment: @ndm metadata caching is enabled and model cache duration is set to +1 years

Comment: I've been monitoring the apache logs (/etc/httpd/logs) but nothing weird to see over there. It looks like the server just isn't responding within the 10000ms limit but that just happens occasionally. Which is odd as we have plenty of resources.

It causes serious problem however as sometimes the fetching of new receipt data times out and subsequently the view doesn't get updated. F.e. users start adding multiple payments because of the not-updated view ...
I also can't replicate the problem myself which makes it hard to test.